# $x=-y$ if and only if $-x=y$

Tags: real-analysis

We started İntroduction to Real Analysis. This question from this course. We did axioms of real  numbers (only additive) and basic math proofs.

**Proposition.** For all $x$, $-(-x)=x$.
Proof. We were done.

**Remark**. Also note that $x=-y$ if and only if $-x=y$ for all $x,y$ as they both ...#missing#... $x+y=0$.

*Proof.* First step. ($\Rightarrow$) If $x=-y$ then $x+y=(-y)+y=0$. Thus, we have $x+y=0$ (since $x$ is additive inverse of $y$) i.e., $y=-x$.

Final step. ($\Leftarrow$)If $-x=y$ then $x=-y$. Thus, We have $x+y=0$ (since $y$ is additive inverse of $x$) i.e., $x=-y$.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: Your second step is a circular reference.

Comment: It is circular in the second part

Comment: How should it become?

Comment: The second step you imediately state what you want to prove.  Not acceptable.  Why does x+y=0 mean y=-x.  And for the first proof what the hell does "we are done" mean?  No, you aren't!  You haven't even started.

Comment: So, what are your definitions and axioms?  Different courses have different definitions and axioms and thus different proofs.  Most, but not all, use field def/axioms.  In my opinion this is the best way but that is an **opinion**; all ways are equivalent.  Apostle rather bizarrely uses a different method.  So in particular, do you know additivegmult inverses actually exist and are unique?